# BIRT InfluxDB integration

Tags: reporting, birt, influxdb

does anyone know of an Eclipse BIRT - InfluxDB integration? Or is there any other BI tool that can be used on top of InfluxDB?

Background: I got some IoT Data collected to an InfluxDB. Parts of the data should be inlcuded in e.g. monthly reports. The people creating the reports do not have a programming background.

Regards, Sebastian

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Or does anyone else? I also want to create an automated report from my data stored in influxdb.